# Checking Nakayama's lemma for a specific example

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Verify Nakayama's lemma that says if 
$IM=M$ then $M=0$ by hand in the particular case where we take our ring $R$ to be $\mathbb{Z}$, our module $M$ to be 
$\mathbb{Z}/16 \mathbb{Z}$, and our ideal 
$I$ to be $(11)$.
In other words: check that 
$IM=M$. I cannot see how this makes sense! How is $M=0$ when $M=\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I feel like the problem you've been assigned makes no sense. Also if $IM=M$ and $I$ were contained in the Jacobson ideal, then $M=0$, which is clearly not the case here. The question you've been assigned, as reported here, makes exactly no sense.

Comment: @jgon the exact wording of the question is `verify nakayama's lemma that says if $IM=M$ then $M=0$ by hand in the particular case where we take our ring $R$ to be $Z$, our module $M$ to be $Z/16Z$, and our ideal $I$ to be $(11)$. In other words: check that $IM = M$'. I cannot see how this makes sense

Comment: I think there's a copy-paste error in the statement of the Nakayama's lemma. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma#Statement) (paraphrased), "Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ and $M$ be a f.g. module over $R$. If $IM = M$, then there exists $r \in R$ with $r \equiv 1 \bmod I$ such that $rM = 0$"

Comment: As Alex Vong is suggesting, I suspect that you are supposed to show that $IM=M$ and that there is $n\equiv 1\pmod{11}$ such that $nM=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The gcd of 11 and 16 is 1. Thus there exists an x,y $\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that 16x + 11y = 1. If we reduce mod 11, this says that 16x $\equiv$ 1 (mod 11). For our case, if x = 9, then 9*16 = 144 = 13(11) + 1. Thus 144*M = 0, since 144 is a multiple of 16.